# How to merge multiple select statement result into single select statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have write stored procedure given below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE StudentDemo @RollNo INT
/*
StudentDemo 504
*/
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentID INT

    --Get the Current RollNo's ID
    SELECT @CurrentID = ID FROM StudentData WHERE RollNo = @RollNo

    SELECT @CurrentID AS 'CurrentID'

    --Previous ID
    SELECT RollNO AS 'PreviousID' FROM StuDentData WHERE ID = @CurrentID - 1

    --Next ID
    SELECT RollNO AS 'NextID' FROM StuDentData WHERE ID = @CurrentID + 1
END
```

I want all the result of  select statement in single one and put result in temporary table

Comment: Are you really trying to get the previous and next just by adding a +1 (or -1) to your ID? What happens if you delete one row? The whole approach looks - uhm - open for enhancements :-) Please provide sample data and expected output!

Comment: ID   RollNo Name
1 501   aa
2 502   bb
3 503   cc
4 504   dd
5 505   ee